# Java : making a lot of URL connections leads to empty content

Tags: java, html, url, connection

I'm trying, via multithreading, to connect to A LOT of URLs for a particular job analysis.

But when doing this, after some time, most connections give me empty answers like this:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body></body>
</html>
```

The same URL will work 1 minute later. But let's say, after running 100 threads spamming connections, it will lead to a lot of empty answers...

Is there any, like, DDOS protection or so? Or is there a limit on connections by my client-side, maybe?

Comment: Connections to *what*? There is no generalized DDoS protection that we can reason about; different servers may have all sorts of different levels, including "none".

Comment: Connections to all those forums posts like this one : 
http://www.all-musculation.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=12462

Comment: If you are trying to access a single host at full speed, there probably is some kind of DoS protection that is kicking in. Crank down the speed to one or two connections per second, for instance.

Comment: Isn't there a way to acces them each time with... like new identifications or ip? Because my analysis is really huge and I will need speed in some way..